# Select values in two sets

Tags: sql

Let's suppose I would like to fetch two users from database `Sarah Connor` and `Kyle Reese`. How to do that using **both first and second names**?

```
select * 
from users 
where 
  first_name in ('Sarah', 'Kyle') and 
  last_name in ('Connor', 'Reese')
```

But, this query is wrong, because it would fetch `Sarah Reese` too. How to fix it? And, the query should be also efficient in terms of **performance**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In MySQL you could use this:

```
select * 
from users 
where 
  (first_name, last_name) in (('Sarah', 'Connor'), ('Kyle', 'Reese'))
```

Otherwise you can use:

```
select * 
from users 
where 
   (first_name = 'Sarah' and last_name = 'Connor') or
   (first_name = 'Kyle' and last_name = 'Reese')
```

Comment: That's not MySQL specific - it's standard SQL. It would also work in other DBMS

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I need!

Comment: The following features outside Core SQL-2008 are used: F641, "Row and table constructors"; T051, "Row types";
F561, "Full value expressions"

Comment: Far be it from me to link to "for Dummies", but, er, here it is, talking about how this was standardised in SQL-92: http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-use-sql-row-value-expressions.html One of the examples is poor because it uses these to emulate a `join`... but it gets the idea across.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for SQL Server,

```
select * 
from users 
where first_name + ' ' + last_name in ('Sarah Connor','Kyle Reese')
```

Comment: Product specific answer, to a question with no dbms specifies. At least tell OP which dbms this is for. (Will probably disqualify index usage too...)